# Function runs twice when using $.when().done

Tags: jquery, function

When I use `$.when().done` the function is called twice rather than one time. I want to run code when a function and all its code is done. And I do this successfully like this...

```
function whenDone() {
  alert("test")
}

$("button").on("click", function() {

  whenDone();

  $.when( whenDone() ).done(function() {
    // DO OTHER STUFF
  });

});
```

The only problem is that the whenDone() function is called 2 times. How can I prevent the function from executing twice and still run code when its finished executing all its content?

This pen shows what I mean. Simply click "button" http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPMopN

Comment: `$.when()` is used with asynchronous functions. The argument should be a `Deferred` object returned by the function that starts the async operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `whenDone();`, `$.when` already calls that function.

Comment: Huh. I thought I had to call the function and then check if its done. That worked.

Comment: @Shabbb I recommend using `$.when` only for asynchronous calls such as `ajax` calls. Otherwise, you do not need it.

Comment: @Shabbb please do not forget to mark the correct answer.

Comment: @Shabbb - But, even more importantly, you don't even need the `$.when()` since it only adds value when it is operating on a promise.  If you're using `$.when()` with a function that is always synchronous, that's just a waste of code and is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

`whenDone` isn't an asynchronous function, so you don't need to use `$.when`. It doesn't return until all its code has executed. Synchronous functions are simply run in order:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    whenDone();
    // Do other stuff
});
```

Comment: I need it to execute separate code only after the function and all its code has executed. Not after the whenDone function is called.

Comment: As mentioned in this answer, your `$.when()` is useless. Code will run sequentially.

Comment: @Shabbb When the `whenDone` function returns, all its code has executed.